# Implement lazy drag & drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to implement a lazy drag and drop operation. I want to show a listview with files to my user, when the user drags a file and drops it into a folder the content should be downloaded and delivered.

I am using the [IDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idataobject.aspx) interface, but my problem is that the *GetData()* method is queried way too early. For instance a drag over the desktop (without any drop involved) will query the *GetData()* method a couple of times. And each of these calls starts the download of the file :/

Now, my question is: What's wrong here - why is the *GetData()* method called without any drop? Is there another way to implement lazy drag & drop operations in .net?

Comment: The problem you will have is listening for the drop event in Explorer, which is when you would like to initiate the download.  You can proof-of-concept this by drag-dropping onto another control in your form, which you will be able to subscribe to the drop event of.

Comment: Yes, this could help me, but it sounds a lot more complicated and binds my dropping to the explorer only. Other targest, that accept filedrops normally, wouldn't be able to get the data. In theory, the drop event should call *IDataObject.GetData()* - and only it should do so. Then I can deliver the data (direct or via download). However there are calls to this functions without an involved drop, which makes this approach unusable.

Comment: Is there no way to delay the download until the receiving end actually asks to see the bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work for you...

On every occurrence of the GetData() do this:

- you'll need some kind of a timer here.
- if your timer is already active, kill it.
- create and start a new timer.  Make it 1sec or determine its duration from the experiment.
- on timer event do what has to be done.

I use similar procedure on many occasions where such workaround is needed.

Comment: The problem here is that the drag could be canceled at all.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way that you could make distinction between completed drag&drop and canceled one?

Comment: Yes, how do you abort your timer in case of an aborted drag&drop?

Comment: If you didn't resolve that by now, I can try to go your way and solve the issues you have...

Answer (score 1):

I think GetData is being called so that the (potential) drop target can determine whether or not it can accept the (potential) drop item(s). Have you considered using a shell extension?

Comment: As far as I understand the [GetDataPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0z723wb.aspx) method should be called at first. Still trying ...